# how can i make the compiler sleep after a particular index of array is processed?

Tags: java, gosu

I am inserting records from an array to a system,since if the count of array records goes beyond 999 system will break , so i want to make the compiler sleep for 2 seconds once 998 records are processed , in Java ..how can I do the same? I am working in Gosu which is a technology similiar to Java 8 .Thanks in Advance

Comment: Sidebar comment: you're confusing the [Compiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler) with something else.

Comment: You can't make the compiler sleep at all. You can make the *current thread* sleep.

Comment: Thanks EJP for correcting me

Answer (score 2):

You may want to use [`Thread.sleep()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep-long-).

```
try {
    Thread.sleep(2000); // 2 seconds
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    // do something if necessary
}
```

Comment: Do we really need an answer when there are thousands of duplicates to this question?

Comment: thanks all, but my question was linke dto gosu technology ,Anyways got the fix from,it was breaking the collection to sub collections and passing ,no need for thread to sleep .Thanks All